# Nested traversal of yaml using jinja2 template

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

a.yaml

```
Adir:
   test1:
    - param1
    - param2
Bdir:  
  test2:
    - param3
    - param4
```

Python code (py3)

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

if __name__ == "__main__":
    yaml = YAML(typ='safe')
    file = './a.yaml'
    ydata = yaml.load(open(file))
    env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader("templatedir"), trim_blocks=True, lstrip_blocks=True)
    gettmp = env.get_template('template.j2')
    test = gettmp.render(dict=ydata)
```

template.j2

```
 {% for dir in dict %}
 {% for test, value in dir.items() %}
 {{ dir }} - {{ test }} - {{ value }}
 {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

I am getting following error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'items'
```

Am I missing anything here? with the jinja2 import the item() method in the template should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to my question:

template.j2

```
 {% for dir,tests in dict.items() %}
 {% for test, value in tests.items() %}
 {{ dir }} - {{ test }} - {{ value }}
 {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Output is:

```
 Adir - test1 - ['param1', 'param2']
 Bdir - test2 - ['param3', 'param4']
```